# Why does an Excel workbook file open automatically?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, microsoft-excel, download, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the strange case of 2 nearly identical Excel workbook downloads in my code, and often on another team member's machine, and sometimes on my machine, when the user clicks *download*, the .xlsx file downloads and then "automatically"' opens without having to explicitly open it.

What could cause an Excel workbook to automatically open as soon as its download finishes?

Regards the first answer, I don't have the suggested property in my Chrome settings:
[image]

Comment: Many things can be at play here: the client browser settings, the computer settings, parameters in the download link, etc... Can you perhaps edit your question to incliude more detail? I think the client browser settings are the most important distinguishing setting.

Comment: Yes, browser setting. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I don't know much more. The only "parameters" in the download link are the id for which spreadsheet to download. My teammate, where this happens more, also suspects browser settings.

Comment: @harrymc Chrome, always latest version

Comment: @ProfK,, are you using any VBA code to download, if yes check the command line , has it set to OPEN FILE,,, or if using TORENT has an option Always open the file,, OR,, hit BROWSER Setting,, Advance,,and clear your Auto Open options.  Next time you download an item, it will be saved instead of opened automatically.!!

Comment: Is the Excel coming from a Sharepoint or OneDrive environment? Can you reproduce the issue reliably (e.g. every 8th download it opens Excel automatically)?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke The Excel is a new Workbook rendered by my code, using the `EPPlus` Excel library. I use a byte array to return a file to the user, there is "middle man" for the workbook. I can't seem to reproduce the issue reliably but have been too busy with higher priority issues for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a setting to open files of certain type automatically.

The first Google hit when I search for `chrome open files automatically` is [this article](https://services.dartmouth.edu/TDClient/1806/Portal/KB/ArticleDet?ID=75023). It explains how to reset this behavior:

> 1. Click on the 3 dots in the top right of your Chrome window and select Settings
> 2. Scroll to the bottom of the page and click on Advanced
> 3. Find the Downloads section
> 4. Click Clear next to Open certain file types automatically after downloading

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I have updated the question to show that I do not have this property in my download settings.